# Passing variables to graphql query with react-apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a problem passing in the variable options into the graphql query. If console.log(ownProps.match.params.id) I get the correct id.

However im getting this error:

> Error: The operation 'selectCustomer' wrapping 'Apollo(Apollo(withRouter(Consumer)))' is expecting a variable: 'id' but it was not found in the props passed to 'Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(withRouter(Consumer))))'

Export

```
const ConsumerWithMutations =  graphql(selectCustomer, {
  name : 'selectCustomer',
  options: (ownProps) => ({
    variables: {
      id: ownProps.match.params.id
    }
  })
})(graphql(deleteCustomer, {
  name: 'deleteCustomer'
})(withRouter(Consumer)))

export default graphql(selectCustomer)(ConsumerWithMutations);
```

Query

```
const selectCustomer = gql`
query selectCustomer($id: String!)
{
  consumer(id: $id) {
    id
    firstname
    lastname
    dateOfBirth
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to wrap your component with the same query HOC twice -- the first time within your definition of `ConsumerWithMutations` and then again inside your export statement.

You don't pass any options into the HOC inside your export statement, so your `selectCustomer` query can't find the `id` variable you specified, which is why you see the error you're getting.

Modify your export statement to this:

```
export default ConsumerWithMutations;
```

and it should work.

I would also highly recommend utilizing `compose` when you're using multiple HOCs like this -- it helps keep code readable. Check out the example [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/higher-order-components.html#compose).

Comment: Thanks so much man! Will def check compose out - was a pretty obvious thing :(

Comment: I had this error whithout passing the right way the id parameter,  using:  options: props => ({ id: props.match.params.parentid }),  I fixed with   options: props => ({  variables: { id: props.match.params.parentid}  }),

Comment: Example link is not working.